# Trust chain working on Windows but not with Firefox and macOS

Tags: c#, macos, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle, x509

We have an intranet application under Windows Server with its own CA. The root (CA) certificate is already installed on all clients /Windows and macOS). The existing server certificate no longer meets [Apple's current requirements](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176) (e.g. 2-year term and use of SAN).

For a new web service I use the existing root certificate and the private key and create a new server certificate via Bouncy Castle.

#### The good

**Windows**

This new server certificate is displayed as valid under Windows, the certificate chain is intact.
[image]

All Windows based clients work as expected.

**OpenSSL**

Verification with OpenSSL is successful:

```
T:\>openssl.exe verify -CAfile ess2016-ess2016server-ca.cer ess2016server.cer
ess2016server.cer: OK
```

#### The bad

**FireFox**

If I import the root certificate into Firefox under Windows, the server certificate is shown as invalid (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER).

**macOS**

The new certificate is also not accepted under macOS (the root certificate is already in the keychain and trusted):

```
$ security verify-cert -p ssl -c ess2016server.cer
Cert Verify Result: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED
```

CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED = The certificate could not be verified back to a root certificate.

#### The question

What I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing for FireFox/macOS? Why is the chain broken?

#### The certificates

This is the root (CA) certificate: ess2016-ess2016server-ca

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            46:29:70:cb:8f:f1:1c:85:44:21:ba:4e:9c:72:8a:9b
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=ess2016-ESS2016SERVER-CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 11 11:22:35 2016 GMT
            Not After : Oct  3 11:22:35 2056 GMT
        Subject: CN=ess2016-ESS2016SERVER-CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b0:fc:42:3a:31:0e:db:df:9c:bd:84:24:5d:cb:
                    cd:39:75:c8:ac:33:a5:b1:55:1d:53:b1:d8:d6:f6:
                    79:e0:34:f8:38:91:1c:50:d4:85:81:9e:c6:b3:db:
                    12:13:7c:4a:dd:40:de:73:37:33:1d:bc:59:43:bf:
                    a9:31:c7:5b:f9:fe:85:cb:12:a5:2b:f0:0f:7a:7a:
                    10:ca:fd:16:8b:21:38:ae:41:23:2f:47:4f:5b:4f:
                    0d:1e:0c:5b:cc:a1:80:66:38:3a:c6:73:35:85:e9:
                    31:e0:ef:77:77:7e:3f:31:66:ed:06:6a:e8:74:dc:
                    7f:d8:d5:cf:16:27:1f:48:d2:54:80:f8:d1:69:21:
                    d9:e8:e7:3b:72:2e:39:dc:e4:f0:10:72:a8:e9:5f:
                    dc:e8:1b:0e:71:6e:93:40:34:90:35:c5:17:ea:73:
                    a3:ee:65:e4:f4:15:3a:ad:e8:71:60:37:10:05:e3:
                    ee:af:96:a4:2a:88:f3:36:6b:33:33:65:ca:c4:c5:
                    c9:b5:7c:bd:95:34:b5:e8:a7:a1:b3:97:55:4c:57:
                    5a:62:0d:6b:70:0e:07:06:57:51:fc:b1:aa:97:9a:
                    d6:00:c5:4b:bb:2d:65:77:da:e4:67:59:a6:65:e9:
                    c5:af:f1:ae:2e:99:d7:1f:eb:6e:b5:bf:5d:e0:0d:
                    4d:bd
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                AF:6A:45:6F:23:44:85:18:A6:80:D1:66:59:67:6B:4B:12:76:33:5C
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         21:68:50:44:43:05:e8:b9:9c:9c:9f:90:da:19:c1:9d:20:d9:
         a8:4a:33:d9:37:84:bd:14:60:54:f8:91:16:1c:d4:e9:ca:5c:
         07:63:64:e5:bf:0c:b4:90:71:b3:63:15:bc:0f:65:6b:eb:27:
         2d:29:9c:b0:0d:fe:b2:1c:4b:61:c0:70:17:53:1e:2e:1d:93:
         e2:e8:ad:ae:ad:d1:ad:31:8b:51:bd:bb:bb:01:e0:96:bc:9a:
         2b:86:0f:b6:8d:50:d3:34:5b:7f:21:1b:46:30:f1:e8:59:b4:
         bb:69:6a:ec:fe:5e:ea:79:60:99:b0:88:30:59:68:4c:58:8a:
         82:d5:14:2d:63:1e:65:fb:c9:23:e9:4d:b9:d4:34:bb:7e:ca:
         1d:54:60:bc:07:55:c9:67:04:fb:66:85:4e:b3:3c:ef:0a:63:
         93:19:eb:72:cc:34:4d:d4:5c:9f:b9:3c:35:f1:51:19:b7:44:
         88:47:0c:91:9d:53:7d:26:ef:2c:78:c3:b7:e7:14:fe:1a:30:
         0e:db:d7:8f:85:29:fb:41:15:87:55:95:45:a8:90:28:06:43:
         d8:6b:76:42:7d:5d:c2:dd:57:a1:e6:f5:ff:d9:78:c3:55:2f:
         eb:42:40:dc:71:2d:94:4b:5e:95:1b:b0:d1:a6:cc:64:89:e4:
         5c:87:62:a9
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDFDCCAfygAwIBAgIQRilwy4/xHIVEIbpOnHKKmzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAj
MSEwHwYDVQQDExhlc3MyMDE2LUVTUzIwMTZTRVJWRVItQ0EwIBcNMTYxMDExMTEy
MjM1WhgPMjA1NjEwMDMxMTIyMzVaMCMxITAfBgNVBAMTGGVzczIwMTYtRVNTMjAx
NlNFUlZFUi1DQTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALD8Qjox
DtvfnL2EJF3LzTl1yKwzpbFVHVOx2Nb2eeA0+DiRHFDUhYGexrPbEhN8St1A3nM3
Mx28WUO/qTHHW/n+hcsSpSvwD3p6EMr9FoshOK5BIy9HT1tPDR4MW8yhgGY4OsZz
NYXpMeDvd3d+PzFm7QZq6HTcf9jVzxYnH0jSVID40Wkh2ejnO3IuOdzk8BByqOlf
3OgbDnFuk0A0kDXFF+pzo+5l5PQVOq3ocWA3EAXj7q+WpCqI8zZrMzNlysTFybV8
vZU0teinobOXVUxXWmINa3AOBwZXUfyxqpea1gDFS7stZXfa5GdZpmXpxa/xri6Z
1x/rbrW/XeANTb0CAwEAAaNCMEAwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgGGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQF
MAMBAf8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFK9qRW8jRIUYpoDRZllna0sSdjNcMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
CwUAA4IBAQAhaFBEQwXouZycn5DaGcGdINmoSjPZN4S9FGBU+JEWHNTpylwHY2Tl
vwy0kHGzYxW8D2Vr6yctKZywDf6yHEthwHAXUx4uHZPi6K2urdGtMYtRvbu7AeCW
vJorhg+2jVDTNFt/IRtGMPHoWbS7aWrs/l7qeWCZsIgwWWhMWIqC1RQtYx5l+8kj
6U251DS7fsodVGC8B1XJZwT7ZoVOszzvCmOTGetyzDRN1FyfuTw18VEZt0SIRwyR
nVN9Ju8seMO35xT+GjAO29ePhSn7QRWHVZVFqJAoBkPYa3ZCfV3C3Veh5vX/2XjD
VS/rQkDccS2US16VG7DRpsxkieRch2Kp
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This is the server certificate: ess2016server

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            39:79:81:5c:2f:ff:23:b1
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=ess2016-ESS2016SERVER-CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 28 00:00:00 2019 GMT
            Not After : Feb 23 00:00:00 2022 GMT
        Subject: CN=ESS2016SERVER
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b9:80:b4:97:6a:f3:cb:c1:15:22:b9:46:4c:1a:
                    79:d3:19:b5:13:b3:e3:af:19:83:b5:dc:0e:50:ef:
                    2b:52:0a:e1:86:71:38:a3:36:ef:bb:22:9d:ce:7f:
                    71:5d:7c:92:1f:41:54:8f:62:ff:07:12:c5:c7:7f:
                    44:b1:92:5d:67:bd:72:1b:a2:e0:cd:36:ac:c5:c5:
                    52:f3:11:7b:5c:88:8d:e6:aa:bd:13:4a:9e:3e:49:
                    95:53:84:29:c7:13:8b:8b:f2:b9:00:94:de:85:e5:
                    53:c0:48:1f:01:37:c7:ee:11:91:9c:cf:e0:6f:9b:
                    01:9b:c1:ac:d0:0a:3c:d8:1c:04:72:43:1a:7c:f7:
                    d2:5f:58:4b:de:96:74:e5:27:70:33:66:3c:33:0c:
                    3d:a5:34:d5:a5:e0:4f:44:db:01:d5:ac:1d:67:91:
                    82:8e:82:69:2e:15:06:7c:0f:64:0c:f7:ae:7a:b1:
                    b2:bf:d4:02:d3:95:8b:70:50:28:a1:c5:4f:35:e8:
                    01:7e:9f:1f:15:24:01:3a:b0:3c:b7:b5:a7:b3:70:
                    42:4d:7c:b1:d1:3a:9a:0f:f3:2d:fb:cd:6e:a1:10:
                    ee:61:78:82:a2:7c:0c:36:63:85:b6:c4:16:31:fe:
                    01:7f:69:00:e1:b8:50:65:25:26:a4:5c:d5:a9:f5:
                    b4:1f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                7B:7E:35:03:B5:71:1C:15:29:0E:DA:70:88:F2:67:7D:8E:4A:9C:42
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:ESS2016SERVER, DNS:ess2016server, DNS:ess2016server.ess2016.internal
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:AF:6A:45:6F:23:44:85:18:A6:80:D1:66:59:67:6B:4B:12:76:33:5C

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         8f:b8:88:17:a4:3c:a3:d8:40:70:ee:a1:e1:39:c5:49:ee:db:
         92:3f:25:b5:9c:b7:9c:2b:94:c4:dc:2c:7e:7d:1e:5e:97:f6:
         3a:ff:9b:99:d6:74:5a:26:16:c3:33:fd:7f:6f:e3:b8:75:81:
         63:19:06:b7:0a:d7:76:9f:bc:03:72:ae:a7:5f:7d:2a:0e:33:
         34:db:18:49:7b:76:32:95:d8:00:71:a7:2f:06:e8:79:d3:5f:
         2a:53:a7:d0:d1:ea:c0:be:32:27:4f:4d:cb:ba:39:9f:b2:71:
         3b:32:7d:5c:a2:2d:81:99:ae:0b:70:af:69:e1:1b:e6:ad:71:
         89:ba:0b:9a:47:a7:28:1a:ba:5c:fb:f7:ce:09:f4:42:9f:48:
         08:27:c9:c0:99:64:84:d4:10:2b:7b:3c:d2:e0:c1:ee:86:f9:
         25:4e:1d:2c:54:4a:5d:46:54:b6:d8:8c:26:01:1f:50:bd:71:
         62:50:4b:bd:2e:84:92:11:a1:53:a2:c8:22:0a:44:d8:50:f2:
         b2:7d:42:c2:35:85:c9:02:1f:d9:91:72:ce:0b:b9:c6:42:1a:
         44:c0:d0:e5:e9:3c:f0:6c:63:ce:b4:d4:25:ef:c4:ef:d9:e2:
         b5:e7:68:a9:ed:30:b1:30:7e:79:dc:01:e0:c1:e1:00:4e:e1:
         d2:7b:8a:d4
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

In short: The **string encoding for the Issuer is different** between root certificate and certificate.

In detail: This article helped a lot https://frasertweedale.github.io/blog-redhat/posts/2018-03-15-x509-dn-attribute-encoding.html

Important part of this article

> This is confusing wording, but in practical terms there are two
> requirements:
>
> 1. The Issuer DN on a certificate must be byte-identical to the Subject DN of the CA that issued it.
> 2. The attribute encodings in a CA’s Subject DN must not change (e.g. when the CA certificate gets renewed).
>
> If a CA violates either of these requirements breakage will ensue.
> Programs that do binary DN comparison will be unable to construct a
> certification path to the CA.

Looking at the encodings of my two certs give these results:

```
T:\ess2016>f:\openssl\openssl.exe x509 -in ess2016server-lo.cer -outform der | f:\openssl\openssl.exe asn1parse -inform der -i
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 808 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 528 cons:  SEQUENCE
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   3 cons:   cont [ 0 ]
   10:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim:    INTEGER           :02
   13:d=2  hl=2 l=  19 prim:   INTEGER           :05FA8D8E0E4FEC91F2832BA6817FB54966D986
   34:d=2  hl=2 l=  13 cons:   SEQUENCE
   36:d=3  hl=2 l=   9 prim:    OBJECT            :sha256WithRSAEncryption
   47:d=3  hl=2 l=   0 prim:    NULL
   49:d=2  hl=2 l=  35 cons:   SEQUENCE
   51:d=3  hl=2 l=  33 cons:    SET
   53:d=4  hl=2 l=  31 cons:     SEQUENCE
   55:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OBJECT            :commonName
   60:d=5  hl=2 l=  24 prim:      **UTF8STRING**        :ess2016-ESS2016SERVER-CA
```

Here encoding is UTF8STRING

```
T:\ess2016>f:\openssl\openssl.exe x509 -in root-ca.pem -outform der | f:\openssl\openssl.exe asn1parse -inform der -i
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 788 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 508 cons:  SEQUENCE
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   3 cons:   cont [ 0 ]
   10:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim:    INTEGER           :02
   13:d=2  hl=2 l=  16 prim:   INTEGER           :462970CB8FF11C854421BA4E9C728A9B
   31:d=2  hl=2 l=  13 cons:   SEQUENCE
   33:d=3  hl=2 l=   9 prim:    OBJECT            :sha256WithRSAEncryption
   44:d=3  hl=2 l=   0 prim:    NULL
   46:d=2  hl=2 l=  35 cons:   SEQUENCE
   48:d=3  hl=2 l=  33 cons:    SET
   50:d=4  hl=2 l=  31 cons:     SEQUENCE
   52:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OBJECT            :commonName
   57:d=5  hl=2 l=  24 prim:      PRINTABLESTRING   :ess2016-ESS2016SERVER-CA
   83:d=2  hl=2 l=  32 cons:   SEQUENCE
   85:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 prim:    UTCTIME           :161011112235Z
  100:d=3  hl=2 l=  15 prim:    GENERALIZEDTIME   :20561003112235Z
  117:d=2  hl=2 l=  35 cons:   SEQUENCE
  119:d=3  hl=2 l=  33 cons:    SET
  121:d=4  hl=2 l=  31 cons:     SEQUENCE
  123:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OBJECT            :commonName
  128:d=5  hl=2 l=  24 prim:      **PRINTABLESTRING**   :ess2016-ESS2016SERVER-CA
```

And here PRINTABLESTRING